# Python Dataframe conversion to R dataframe with null values

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am converting null python dataframes to r dataframes using rpy2 package which works really well except that I have nulls in the my columns causing an error during conversion

```
patients_list_df = load_df_state('temp_data/patients_list_df.csv')
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    patients_list_df = ro.conversion.py2rpy(patients_list_df)
```

> /Users/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py:63:
> UserWarning: Error while trying to convert the column
> "term_dt_datetime". Fall back to string conversion. The error is:
> Series can only be of one type, or None (and here we have <class
> 'float'> and <class 'str'>).   % (name, str(e))) AttributeError:
> 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

I have 5 dataframes some of the null values are represented in python pandas as `NaN` some as `NaT` but I am not sure how to address this in R code. The columns will be processed according to their respective data type later on.

Versions:

pandas==1.0.1

rpy2~=3.3.5

Comment: The rpy2 version you are using may matter a lot. `pandas`'s handling of NAs changed relatively recently.

Comment: updated with the versions

Answer (score 0):

`rpy2` is quick to shy away from guessing what the type of a column (`Series`) in a `pandas` `DataFrame` might be. Here what is likely happening is that you have a column of type `numpy.dtype('O')`, that is each item in that column / numpy 1D-array can be a Python object of any type.

The default for `rpy2` is to check whether the types in the array are homogeneous: only one type, or `None`/`NaN`/`pandas.isna()` returns `True`, for all items in the array. The code is here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/blob/v3.3.x/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py#L170

So in theory there should not be an issue. If you are able to provide a minimal self-contained example to reproduce it, it will be easier to see what it happening.